# What is footer in table view IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

What is footer. When we will use that. I have a sample code in which they used method `viewForFooterInSection`. What it will do... Any idea?

Comment: perhaps if you are allowed to share the portion of the code, it would be helpful to understand and give an answer :-)

Comment: Thanks all for your replies, From my understanding from your replies So if I want to make an empty space to show any title or header between Cell, we will use that. If so how can we decide where we need to show the header, I simply return a view from that method, It makes my cell height bigger. can anyone please give me any sample codes to understand it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `UITableView` can be considered as made of three main elements, a "list" - containing sections and cells, a header and a footer.

The list area can contain from 1 to many sections and in a grouped table view you may also have headers and footers for sections. Assuming you are talking about table footers and not section footers the following is my answer:

The table's footer is what it says on the tin... you might want to use it to display some additional information about the data of the table view.

Check the App Store, Apple display some information about the user who is logged into the store at the bottom of the table view (in some areas).

I sometimes use this footer view as an area to display a `UIActivityIndicatorView`, and initiate a kind of "fetch more" feature for any API related data.

Answer (score 8):

It is used as a view at the end of the section, placed after the cells in the section, and before the header view of the next section.
[Here is the appropriate docs link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW4) and a photo from that page:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [UITableViewDelegate protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595342/text-in-header-footer-of-table-section-iphone) allows you to return views for the header and footer of a section. Simply implement this method and return a UILabel filled with the text you want to display.

Answer (score 2):

In  `viewForFooterInSection` you can add customized labels or other objects to display in footer section.
From the below two links you can batter understand.

[Update section footer title in UITableView without reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929675/update-section-footer-title-in-uitableview-without-reloading)

[Setting a basic footer to a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111748/setting-a-basic-footer-to-a-uitableview)